# Getting google sheet dropdown values of a cell with sheet api using javascript

Tags: google-sheets-api

I am trying to get all the values from a dropdown list of a cell in google sheet 
[google sheet dropdown screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VbL14.png)

however in the json return that i am getting from the sheet api, I only get the selected value and not the list of all the values of the dropdown. How can i the whole list?

the ajax code is:

> "GET", 
>   "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/"+sheetId+"/values/Sheet1?key="+apiKey+""

[json return screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8SNy.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

That's the expected outcome. Sheets API only fetches values which are currently visible on the cells. There is no way to get the hidden whole list. Check [Reading and Writing](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values) for more info.